# Does iphone have an activity/ diagnostic log

Tags: iphone, music.app

Don't know whats going on ... I am listening to music and all of a sudden it gets paused. The impression is that i got a call without actually getting it.

I suspect one application, but have no proof its the one.

Is there an activity log i can take a look to see what happens when it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's just a crash log...

Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage > Diagnostic & Usage Data

However, my experience is that it's more likely that your headphones have a fault in the cable or inline remote or dirt in your headphone jack or dock connector (pre-iPhone 5) which is causing it to pause randomly.

This is very common, especially if the headphones don't sit fully into the jack because of lint at the bottom.